# How to define and read array of objects from spring's application.properties?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

In my Java class, I want to read a variable that will give me a list of tokens in one shot and my token is an object with fields as name, value, and enabled.

```
@Value("authorised_applications")
private List<Token> tokenList;
```

How do I define this in my application.properties file so that I can read all tokens at once.
For an instance, I have tokens like:

```
token1
- value: 123456,
- name: specialToken,
- enabled: true

token2
- value: 56173,
- name: newToken,
- enabled: false
```

I have tried other links but could not find a way to read this all at once.

Want to create bean like this

```
@ConfigurationProperties("authorised")
@Configuration
public class AppTokenConfiguration {
    private final List<TokenStore.Token> tokenList = new ArrayList<>();

    @Bean
    public TokenStore getTokenStore() {
        return new TokenStore(tokenList.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(TokenStore.Token::getToken, Function.identity())));
    }
}
```

Comment: authorised is a odd way of write authorized :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `@ConfigurationProperties` with `prefix` on the Class which has properties to be configured from `application.properties`.

> application.properties:

```
my.tokenList[0].name=test1
my.tokenList[0].value=test2
my.tokenList[0].enabled=true

my.tokenList[1].name=test3
my.tokenList[1].value=test4
my.tokenList[1].enabled=false

server.port=8080
```

> Student.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@ConfigurationProperties("my")
@Component
public class Student {

    private final List<Token> tokenList = new ArrayList<>();

    public List<Token> getTokenList() {
        return tokenList;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "TestNow [tokenList=" + tokenList + "]";
    }
}
```

> Token.java

```
public class Token {

    private String value;
    private String name;
    private boolean enabled;

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return enabled;
    }

    public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        this.enabled = enabled;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Token [value=" + value + ", name=" + name + ", enabled=" + enabled + "]";
    }

}
```

> ValidateStudent.java

```
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class ValidateStudent {

    @Autowired
    private Student student;

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        System.out.println("printing Student Object---> " + student);
    }

}
```

> Proof(output):

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::       (v2.6.0-SNAPSHOT)

2021-10-20 21:17:30.083  INFO 14632 --- [           main] c.e.S.SpringBootCollectionsApplication   : Starting SpringBootCollectionsApplication using Java 14.0.2 on Machine with PID 14632 (D:\workspaces\Oct20_app_properties\SpringBootCollections\target\classes started by D1 in D:\workspaces\Oct20_app_properties\SpringBootCollections)
2021-10-20 21:17:30.088  INFO 14632 --- [           main] c.e.S.SpringBootCollectionsApplication   : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2021-10-20 21:17:31.869  INFO 14632 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2021-10-20 21:17:31.891  INFO 14632 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2021-10-20 21:17:31.891  INFO 14632 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.53]
2021-10-20 21:17:32.046  INFO 14632 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2021-10-20 21:17:32.046  INFO 14632 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1869 ms
printing Student Object---> TestNow [tokenList=[Token [value=test2, name=test1, enabled=true], Token [value=test4, name=test3, enabled=false]]]
2021-10-20 21:17:32.654  INFO 14632 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2021-10-20 21:17:32.675  INFO 14632 --- [           main] c.e.S.SpringBootCollectionsApplication   : Started SpringBootCollectionsApplication in 3.345 seconds (JVM running for 3.995)
```

Edit Answer:

> BeanConfig Class:

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {
   
    @Autowired
    private AppTokenConfiguration appTokenConfiguration;

    @Bean
    public TokenStore getTokenStore() {
        return new TokenStore(appTokenConfiguration.getTokenList().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(TokenStore.Token::getToken, Function.identity())));
    }
}
```

> PropertyConfigClass:

```
@ConfigurationProperties("authorised")
@Component
public class AppTokenConfiguration {

    private final List<TokenStore.Token> tokenList = new ArrayList<>();
    
    public void getTokenList(){
     return tokenList;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do we have getter in Student.java?

Comment: Here Student is kind of config class, hence all the properties defined in this Class should definitely have getters, so that these properties can can be accessed in other classes

Comment: I want to create a bean like in question edit. How can i do that? Right now token store is not loaded with values. Did exactly in answer.

Added code in question edit

Comment: try the edited answer

Comment: Working now. Can you explain me what was problem with my approach? Thanks

Comment: In your proposed code, you are accessing the property bean without loading it prior, hence separating property config and app config will make sure the property config bean can be accessible in app config classs.